# How can I remove a document from an array?

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, unset

I have inserted a document with this structure

```
{ 
  "_id" : ObjectId("5708bf40a86e6f5bd1f45354"),
  "companyId" : ObjectId("5708bed6a86e6f5bd1f4534f"),
  "descriptions" : [ 
       { "id" : ObjectId("5708bf40a86e6f5bd1f45351"), "description" : "test" },
       { "id" : ObjectId("5708bf40a86e6f5bd1f45352"), "description" : "test1" },
       { "id" : ObjectId("5708bf40a86e6f5bd1f45353"), "description" : "test2" } 
   ]
}
```

and now I'm trying to modify the array by removing an object which is matching some criteria - in this case I need to remove the object with a specific `id`.

Here is what I'm doing so far, without any success

```
public void deleteCustomField(final String descriptionId, final ObjectId companyId){
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = setCollection(CUSTOM_FIELDS_COLLECTION);

    collection.updateOne(and(eq("companyId", companyId), eq("descriptions.id", new ObjectId(descriptionId))), new Document("$unset", new Document("descriptions.description", "")));
}
```

This is the `setCollection` method

```
private MongoCollection<Document> setCollection(final String collectionName){
    return db.getCollection(collectionName); 
}
```

The `updateOne` does nothing at all. I know that my query is looking strange, but I can't understand what is going on and how to remove the document from the array. I also tried with `$pull` but I had no luck at all.

I know that I'm missing something small and really basic here, but as a MongoDB beginner, I'm not able to spot it.

Can you give me a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to replace 
`new Document("$unset", new Document("descriptions.description", ""))` 
by 
`new Document("$pull", new Document("descriptions.id", new ObjectId(descriptionId)))`.
See the doc for the [pull operator](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#up._S_pull).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, after some good documentation read I managed to get it working.

Comment: You are welcome. Is my solution working? If you found something else which fits better to what you wanted, please add it as an answer.